# Problem with executing interactive C programs using PHP

Tags: php, exec

I'm having problems with executing C programs using PHP.
I have just used exec() function to execute C file in the system.
The problem is that I cannot able to give the run-time inputs to the C-program.
When I used the scanf() function in C, the system automatically takes some default values(garbage values) as an input and produces some output. How can I overcome that problem.
Please give me the code to make the C-program execution interactive in PHP.

Comment: Interaction is not possible with exec. Only STDIN and STDOUT.

Answer (score 0):

you must use popen("yourprogram","w") to run external executable and give input to the program from your script. http://php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php

Answer (score 0):

If you need to pass some input to your C program and get back the results, you should use [`proc_open`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php). The sample on manual page explains everything, so I'll neither invent another one nor just copy it here.